# How do i read Nfc-V ISO 15693 tags in an Windows Phone 8 application?

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc, iso-15693

Is there a way to read NfcV (ISO 15693) tags that are not NDEF formatted in an Windows Phone 8 App?

**Edit:** The tag IS formatted. It not NDEF formatted.

**Edit** For future readers:
From  [UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/3531845-add-low-level-rfid-functionality) i have now got the following.

> We are happy to report that accessing non-NDEF formatted tags feature is enabled with Windows Phone 8.1, and will only be supported with the new devices launching with new PN547 chipset. This feature is currently not available for devices upgraded to Windows Phone 8.1 from previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that Windows Phone 8 **only supports NDEF formatted tags** you'll need to format them **before** you can read them in a Windows Phone 8 app.

Comment: It says that the tag type is  SL2 ICS2001 (ICODE SLI). The AFI is proprietary(sub-family-7). So it is formatted. But not NDEF formatted i think.